# check if a function is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

what i'm trying to do is to show when the function its done/ready the process ... i try this code but didn't work ... i try with ".done" but still didn't work ... how i can see when the function its ready ?

this is the code what i try ...

HTML:

```
 <div class="Load_Div"></div>
 <br /><br />
 <div class="Result_Data"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
  function Load_HTML() {
   $('.Load_Div').load('file.php', function() {
   });
  }

  Load_HTML().ready( function() { 
      $( ".Result_Data" ).text( "Function Ready" ); 
  } );
```

This is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/w9Xf5/

Comment: Hmmm.. You could try having the `ready` callback on the actual div that is being manipulated.

Answer (score 3):

[Only the document](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) has a `ready()` method, no other elements, functions or whatever has a ready method.

As for your function, that is always ready, but as you're doing ajax, what you're really trying to do is check if the ajax call is finished, and jQuery has built in callbacks and deferreds (which load() does not seem to expose, so `done()` won't work) for this :

```
function Load_HTML(callback) {
    $('.Load_Div').load('file.php', callback);
}

Load_HTML(function () {
    $(".Result_Data").text("Function Ready");
});
```

Comment: did you try it locally where you have acess to those php files? You can't access them via jsfiddle..

Comment: if i remove the function() its working but with that function where i have Scan() is not working anymore ...

Comment: What is Scan()? You are of course running this on a wamp server or something similar, and not directly from the file system ?

Comment: when i load the php files is give me some div what i scan the divs after ... im running the script on my website ... not wamp ...

Answer (score 2):

You could create your own callback

```
function Load_HTML( callback ) {
   $('.Load_Div').load('file.php', callback );
}
```

**And then**

```
Load_HTML( function() {
   $( ".Result_Data" ).text( "Function Ready" );
});
```

Comment: did you try it locally where you have acess to those php files? You can't access them via jsfiddle..

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `Load_HTML().ready()` and insert `$( ".Result_Data" ).text( "Function Ready" );` into the callback function from your `.load()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Deferred-object and give this a lot of functions like additional loading of php-script to process. After each call of the array of functions the process can be evaluated. [Please take a look an this JQuery-API for further informations](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/).